# How to plot intersecting ranges in Excel/R/Matlab

Tags: r, excel, matlab, graph, charts

Any idea about how to plot intersecting ranges in Excel or R or Matlab

my table looks like this

> Start pos  End pos 
>     5              10 
>     7              12 
>  
>   1              3

I would like to color differently all lines and intersections

Thanks

Suleyman

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of gantt chart? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear what you require, but the series as shown plotted as a stacked bar chart in Excel, with Series 1 and 3 without fill and gradient fill for Series 5 produces:

[image: SO20480387 example]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
ranges <- data.frame(x=factor(1:3), ymin=c(5,7,1), ymax=c(10,12,3))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ranges) + 
  geom_linerange(aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, color=x),size=2) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=ymin, color=x),shape=1, size=5) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=ymax, color=x),shape=1, size=5) +
  coord_flip() + labs(x="",y="")
```

[image]

Comment: something like this, but I need all in one line e.g. y=2 
and I need to color differently where the intersection occurs 
in this case 2 and 3 intersects